# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). f you meant to render a collection of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.

I'm trying to develop an App using React for first time, I'm following a course at Platzi, but I've been having a problem that I don't know how to fix here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './App/App.css';

ReactDOM.render( <App />,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Screen of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNc4K.png)

I thought it was a bug so I ran again my local server but it doesn't work. I'll kepp trying to fix it.

Comment: Error is not here. It's somewhere in App or inner component. check whether you add a JSON inside template brackets {...}

Comment: may you show App.js file?

Comment: Finally I find the error it was that I didn't use {} in order to send the props 

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Modal( {Children} ){
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    Children,
    document.getElementById('modal')
  );
};

export { Modal };